# Sorting MySQL query using PHP with results of 3 date fields in one table in order of most recent from any of the 3 fields

Tags: mysql

I tried this but it is not working correctly.

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM coi
      order by 
      CASE
      WHEN Lexpire >= Uexpire AND Lexpire >= Cexpire
           THEN Lexpire
      WHEN Uexpire >= Cexpire
           THEN Uexpire
      ELSE Cexpire
      END
      ASC";
```

Comment: It doesn't make any sense to change the sort order *per record*.  Sort order is applied to the entire result set.  It's not really clear what you're trying to accomplish.  Can you elaborate, to include sample data and the desired result?

Comment: I have to track expiration dates of Certificate of Insurance expiration dates. Liability, Auto, Umbrella, and comp. Many times contractors take different policies and for instance I have one contractor that Liabilty, Auto, and Umbrella expires 2023-01-01 but their Comp expires 2022-09-30. That should be near top of query result since Comp will expire soon but it keeps showing up down the list.

Answer (score 0):

MySql has the handy functions `greatest` and `least` that may be what you need here

```
order by greatest(Lexpire, Uexpire, Cexpire);
```

See [example Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4b3e645dac0b063e58270bf97fbce494)

Comment: HMM? Tried it but the Cexpire has a date that is being ignored. It should be near top of list. I got no results as I forget ending quote first time!'

Comment: @Dean - no results? This won't filter any rows, just determine which column is used for ordering [see demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4b3e645dac0b063e58270bf97fbce494)

Comment: This is giving me same result as my original post.  Not sure how to post clean example result in here. This is working but same as original query. $sql="SELECT * FROM coi ORDER BY greatest(Lexpire, Uexpire, Cexpire, Aexpire)";  Cexpire is landing down the list. Not sure how to insert result example.

Comment: I have to track expiration dates of Certificate of Insurance expiration dates. Liability, Auto, Umbrella, and comp. Many times contractors take different policies and for instance I have one contractor that Liabilty, Auto, and Umbrella expires 2023-01-01 but their Comp expires 2022-09-30. That should be near top of query result since Comp will expire soon but it keeps showing up down the list.

Comment: Hey, I think it works! I changed greatest to least and on a quick look it appears correct. I'll do more testing but I think this is good! Thank You. To be thorough here is my query. $sql="SELECT * FROM coi ORDER BY least(Lexpire, Uexpire, Cexpire, Aexpire)";

Comment: *it is not working* does not tell anyone what is actually wrong with your query or what you are expecting - we would need to see examples of your data for that. "most recent" suggests the *greatest* value but maybe you actually mean the reverse...?